# Converting large decimal input to hexadecimal output in a 256 bit array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a written a code to convert a large number based on the use input to hexadecimal number. However when the result is printed, the only part of the number is converted to hexadecimal and there are other random values in the array.

for example: 
decimal = 1234567891012 ---- the hexa would = 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 65 00 6b 42 48 71 fb 08 44

the last four vales (`71 FB 08 44`) are the correct hexadecimal value, but the others are incorrect

i am using uint8_t buf[];

Code:

```
int main()
{
  uint8_t buf[] = {0};

 long int i,a;

      printf("Enter Number: ");
      scanf("%d", &buf);

      printf("\n");
      printf("Input #: ");

      /* put a test vector */
      for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
         {
         printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
          }
           printf("\n\n");

          printf("\n\n");

      printf("%d\n",sizeof(buf));


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: for set?? what does that mean?

Comment: `random values` usually means you didn't initialize your array to something valid, so it's garbage.

Comment: @Aniket - OP meant "four" not "for". The last 4 bytes are correct.

Comment: 1234567891012 in hexa is 11F71FB0844

Comment: I smell integer overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you posted code the problems become more apparent:

First this:

```
uint8_t buf[] = {0};
```

Is no good. You need to assign a size to your array, (or make it dynamic), that's why you're getting "garbage" when you go to access the elements. For now, we can just give it an arbitrary size:

```
uint8_t buf[100] = {0};
```

That fixes the "garbage" values problem.

Second problem is your scan if is expecting a normal `int` sized value: `"%d"` you need to tell it a to look for a bigger values, something like:

```
scanf("%llu", &buf[0]);
```

Still, you should validate your input against the [limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/). Make sure what the user inputs is in the range of LONG_MAX or INT_MAX or whatever type you have.

Comment: Of course, `long long unsigned` will only give a number up to 64 bits for anything that you can easily get your hands on. For larger numbers, the number itself will have to be stored as multiple parts - GMP as suggested in a previous answer would work, or you could probably write a few bits of code by hand to convert a string to integer and convert it out to hex.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: since you've not provided the source code, I shall assume a few things:

this happens because you've used `unsigned int` to store the decimal, which is 32 bit only on your computer. Use a `unsigned long` to store a decimal that big.

`unsigned long decimal = 12345678901012L;`

And for 16 byte decimal, use [GMP Lib](http://gmplib.org/).

--- edit ---

You must use `scanf("%lu", &decimal)` to store into a long decimal. The scanf("%d", &decimal) only copies "integer(signed)" which probably is 32 bit on your machine!